# How do you prevent buffer overflow using fgets?

Tags: c, overflow

So far I have been using `if statements` to check the size of the user-inputted strings. However, they don't see to be very useful: no matter the size of the input, the `while loop` ends and it returns the input to the main function, which then just outputs it.

I don't want the user to enter anything greater than 10, but when they do, the additional characters just overflow and are outputted on a newline. The whole point of these `if statements` is to stop that from happening, but I haven't been having much luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 10

char *readLine(char *buf, size_t sz) {
  int true = 1;

  while(true == 1) {
    printf("> ");
    fgets(buf, sz, stdin);
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;

    if(strlen(buf) < 2 || strlen(buf) > sz) {
      printf("Invalid string size\n");
      continue;
    }

    if(strlen(buf) > 2 && strlen(buf) < sz) {
      true = 0;
    }
  }

  return buf;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char buffer[SIZE];

  while(1) {
    char *input = readLine(buffer, SIZE);
    printf("%s\n", input);
  }
}
```

Any help towards preventing buffer overflow would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please explain, based on e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets, how the parameter `count` does not help you with preventing buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

In case that string inside the file is longer that 10 chars, your `fgets()` reads only the first 10 chars into `buf`. And, because these chars doesn't contain the trailing `\n`, function `strcspn(buf, "\n")` returns 10 - it means, you are trying to set to 0 an `buf[10]`, so it is over `buf[]` boundaries (max index is 9).

Additionally, never use `true` or `false` as the name of variable - it totally diminishes the code. Use something like 'ok' instead.

Finally: please clarify, what output is expected in case the file contains string longer than 10 characters. It should be truncated?

Answer (score 1):

When the user enters in a string longer than sz, your program processes the first sz characters, but then when it gets back to the fgets call again, stdin already has input (the rest of the characters from the user's first input). Your program then grabs another up to sz characters to process and so on.

The call to strcspn is also deceiving because if the "\n" is not in the sz chars you grab than it'll just return sz-1, even though there's no newline.

After you've taken input from stdin, you can do a check to see if the last character is a '\n' character. If it's not, it means that the input goes past your allowed size and the rest of stdin needs to be flushed. One way to do that is below. To be clear, you'd do this only when there's been more characters than allowed entered in, or it could cause an infinite loop.

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
{}
```

However, trying not to restructure your code too much how it is, we'll need to know if your buffer contains the newline before you set it to 0. It will be at the end if it exists, so you can use the following to check.

```
int containsNewline = buf[strlen(buf)-1] == '\n'
```

Also be careful with your size checks, you currently don't handle the case for a strlen of 2 or sz. I would also never use identifier names like "true", which would be a possible value for a bool variable. It makes things very confusing.